# Boostrap3 Nav-bar does't work in IE8 when I add container and Rows. but works without container rows. Works in FF/Chrome?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, tabs, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am having trouble getting nav-tabs to work in boostrap under IE8, but only when I add the grid (rows).   Seems to work fine under FF and Chrome, but I am having no luck with IE8.  Can anyone see what is wrong here with this sample example?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example of Twitter Bootstrap 3 Dynamic Tabs</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="bs-example">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionA">Section A</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionB">Section B</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#dropdown1">Dropdown1</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#dropdown2">Dropdown2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="row">

        <div id="sectionA" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <h3>Grid box 1</h3>
            <p>Aliquip placeat salvia cillum iphone. Seitan aliquip quis cardigan american apparel, butcher voluptate nisi qui. Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua, retro synth master cleanse. Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica. Reprehenderit butcher retro keffiyeh dreamcatcher synth.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="sectionA" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <h3>Grid Box 2</h3>
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ultricies condimentum velit vel scelerisque. Nam id libero sit amet libero 
             ultrices interdum dignissim nec lorem. Maecenas placerat massa sit amet augue interdum rutrum. Fusce vel lectus arcu. Quisque quis elit et lorem suscipit
             faucibus a ut odio. Proin ut ante consectetur dui mattis pulvinar non quis neque. Proin ultrices lectus vel orci lacinia a iaculis niipiscing ac. Quisque dolor tellus, porta in ultrices sit amet, luctus sed nunc. </p>
       </div>
       </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div id="sectionB" class="tab-pane fade">
        <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h3>Section B</h3>
            <p>Vestibulum nec erat eu nulla rhoncus fringilla ut non neque. Vivamus nibh urna, ornare id gravida ut, mollis a magna. Aliquam porttitor condimentum nisi, eu viverra ipsum porta ut. Nam hendrerit bibendum turpis, sed molestie mi fermentum id. Aenean volutpat velit sem. Sed consequat ante in rutrum convallis. Nunc facilisis leo at faucibus adipiscing.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div id="dropdown1" class="tab-pane fade">
        <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h3>Dropdown 1</h3>
            <p>WInteger convallis, nulla in sollicitudin placerat, ligula enim auctor lectus, in mollis diam dolor at lorem. Sed bibendum nibh sit amet dictum feugiat. Vivamus arcu sem, cursus a feugiat ut, iaculis at erat. Donec vehicula at ligula vitae venenatis. Sed nunc nulla, vehicula non porttitor in, pharetra et dolor. Fusce nec velit velit. Pellentesque consectetur eros.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="dropdown2" class="tab-pane fade">
        <div id="dropdown1" class="tab-pane fade">
        <div class="row">
            <h3>Dropdown 2</h3>
            <p>Donec vel placerat quam, ut euismod risus. Sed a mi suscipit, elementum sem a, hendrerit velit. Donec at erat magna. Sed dignissim orci nec eleifend egestas. Donec eget mi consequat massa vestibulum laoreet. Mauris et ultrices nulla, malesuada volutpat ante. Fusce ut orci lorem. Donec molestie libero in tempus imperdiet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Also, try changing the links to be either all `https` or all `http`; you're mixing them currently, and I have a suspicion that this could matter for Respond.js to be able to do its magic.

How exactly are the tabs "not working" for you?

Are any JavaScript or other errors reported in the error console?